# invalid character result after reading Zürich VB.net

Tags: vb.net, streamreader, streamwriter

I am having a problem writing a string like a word "Zürich" the output became "Zï¿½rich"

I am using StreamReader and StreamWriter.

Anyone can help me with this.

Code: below

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim sReport As String       
        Dim strline As String
        Dim objSR As StreamReader
        Dim objSW As StreamWriter
        sReport = "C:\InvalidChar1.txt"
        Try

            objSW = New StreamWriter(sReport)

            objSR = New StreamReader("C:\InvalidChar.txt")

            Do
                strline = objSR.ReadLine

                objSW.WriteLine(strline)

            Loop While objSR.EndOfStream <> True


            objSW.Close()
            objSR.Close()

        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: What are you using to read the file? What encoding?

Comment: @Oded I update my post the code is there.

Comment: What is the original encoding of the file? How did you create it and using what encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default both `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` will use the UTF-8 encoding.

If this is **not** the original encoding of the file, I'd expect to see these issues - make sure the file is a UTF-8 file.

Comment: manage to correct the issue by: declaring       Dim objSW As New StreamWriter(sReport, False, Encoding.Default)
        objSR = New StreamReader(sIn, Encoding.Default)

Comment: @user870510 - Meaning the original file was in UTF16.

Comment: one more thing what character is "ü"

Comment: @user870510 - Looks like a `u` with an umlaut.

Comment: @odel so I can call "ü" is a UTF16?

Comment: @user870510 - No. UTF16 and UTF8 are Unicode encodings. They both would be able to encode this character.

Comment: @user870510 - A character is a character. You can encode it whatever way you want. Unicode is not an encoding - it is a standard, mapping characters to certain values. UTF8 and UTF16 are some Unicode encodings. The character you posted - `ü` **is** defined in the standard. I believe it is a `u` with an umlaut.

Comment: @user870510 - My name is Oded. Not Odel.